# How to store connection string in Azure Vault and map it back to the configuration settings in Azure Web App?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault, azure-webapps, azure-web-app-for-containers

I am using Azure Web App service. Currently, I am storing the plain connection string to the database, Azure storage in the Application Settings section in the configuration tab of the Web App Service.

Instead of storing the plain connection string in configuration. How can I store the connection string in Azure Vault, then reference it in the Application setting so that the plain connection string are not stored in the configuration settings?

Comment: What kind of CI/CD are you using? You can include an [Azure Key Vault step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops)

Comment: I am using DevOps pipeline to build docker image and then push it to a specific slot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to reference Key Vault in Azure Web Apps.  You can do a complete reference:

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret/)
```

Or you can use the alterative:

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=myvault;SecretName=mysecret)
```

In order to read secrets from Key Vault, you need to have a vault created and give your app permission to access it.

1. Create a key vault by following the Key Vault quickstart.
2. Create a managed identity for your application.

   - Key Vault references will use the app's system assigned identity by default, but you can specify a user-assigned identity.
3. Create an access policy in Key Vault for the application identity you created earlier. Enable the "Get" secret permission on this policy. Do not configure the "authorized application" or `applicationId` settings, as this is not compatible with a managed identity.

Full steps on setting this up:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references

Comment: Thank you! I am unable to get it to work. Perhaps something I am doing wrong. I created Identity service called "PrivateIdentity". In the Azure App Service, I navigated to Identity tab and then under "User assigned" and added "PrivateIdentity". Then in the Configuration tab, I updated the value of my appsettings to `@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=thePrivateURL)`. Then in the Azure Key Vault, under the "Access polices" I assigned `Get` and `List` permissions to the "PrivateIdentity". But the app isn't able to access it still. Any idea what I did wrong or should check for?

Comment: When using `@Microsoft.KeyVault()` does Azure Web App parse that and replace it with the actual secret before it pass it to my app? In other words, will my app just get the actual password instead of `@Microsoft.KeyVault()`?

Comment: When working properly, the Azure Web App will resolve the key vault referenced key and store the actual password in an ENV variable at runtime.  If a reference is not resolved properly, the reference value will be used instead. This means that for application settings, an environment variable would be created whose value has the `@Microsoft.KeyVault(...)` syntax